# Numpy array size different when saved to disk (compared to nbytes)

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible that a flat numpy 1d array's size (`nbytes`) is 16568 (~16.5kb) but when saved to disk, has a size of >2 mbs?

I am saving the array using numpy's `numpy.save` method. Dtype of array is `'O'` (or `object`).

Also, how do I save that flat array to disk such that I get approx similar size to `nbytes` when saved on disk? Thanks

Comment: With `object` dtype, the array itself just contains pointers to objects else were in memory.  `np.save` writes `pickle` representations of each of those objects to the file.  So depending on the nature of those objects, the file size could well be much larger than the `nbytes` of the parent array.

Comment: how do you determine the size of the numpy object in memory?

Comment: @hpaulj i think you are right. Otherwise, there is no obvious reason why a flat array of longs is showing this behavior.

Comment: @kevinkayaks: by using 'array.nbytes' feature of the numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

For others references, From numpy documentation:

> numpy.ndarray.nbytes attribute
>
> ndarray.nbytes Total bytes consumed by the elements of the array.
>
> Notes
>
> Does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the
> array object.

So, the nbytes just considers elements of the array.